# How do I get certain details from a Simple XML Object?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I've retrieved data from an XML file like so

```
$response = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

print_r displays the following

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[artist] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [type] => Group
                [id] => b9fb5447-7f95-4a6a-a157-afed2d7b9f4c
            )

        [name] => He Is Legend
        [sort-name] => He Is Legend
        [country] => US
        [area] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 489ce91b-6658-3307-9877-795b68554c98
                    )

                [name] => United States
                [sort-name] => United States
                [iso-3166-1-code-list] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [iso-3166-1-code] => US
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

So I can output fields like name and country by

```
echo $response->artist->name;
echo $response->artist->country;
```

However I'm stuck when it comes to being able to access data in the attribute arrays.
How can I get the type of group from the first attributes array for example?

**Edit**

I'm also trying to return the details from a function like so

```
func getDetails($id) {

$response = simplexml_load_file('http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/'.$id);
$data = array();
$data['type'] = $response->artist->attributes()->type;
$data['country'] = $response->artist->country;

return $data;
}

print_r(getDetails());
```

Gives me

```
MusicBrainz Object
(
)
```

Comment: `$response->artist->attributes()` will return an array of key/value pairs for the element attributes

Answer (score 1):

You can access them using the [`attributes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method:

```
echo $response->artist->attributes()->type;
```

The [example #5](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-5461) in the SimpleXML documentation shows another example.

Comment: Thanks, that successfully outputs the value. However, I'm doing this inside of a function and trying to save the value to an array to return it.

After returning the data I'm left with an empty object. Any ideas on what I can do here?

Comment: @NickShears: How are you using this inside the function? Without seeing the relevant code, I can't help. :)

Comment: Never mind sorted it, I needed to cast the values as strings when saving them to the array and I was getting an empty result due to assigning the result of the function to a variable with the same name of an object.

Comment: With the id `489ce91b-6658-3307-9877-795b68554c98` i got as a result `Array ( [type] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Group ) [country] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => US ) )`. You forgot to add the argument in `print_r(getDetails());`.

Comment: i meant the id `b9fb5447-7f95-4a6a-a157-afed2d7b9f4c` ;)

Comment: @user2577405: You're missing the function parameter in your function call. You need to call it as `print_r(getDetails('65f4f0c5-ef9e-490c-aee3-909e7ae6b2ab'));`. [Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/VrqvAz).